# std::jthread runs a member function from another member function

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zconf.h>
#include <thread>

class JT {
public:
    std::jthread j1;

    JT() {
        j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this, std::stop_token());
    }

    void init(std::stop_token st={}) {

        while (!st.stop_requested()) {
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
            sleep(1);
        }
        std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
    }
};

void init_2(std::stop_token st = {}) {
    while (!st.stop_requested()) {
        std::cout << "Hello 2" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Bye 2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    JT *jt = new JT();
    std::jthread j2(init_2);
    sleep(5);
    std::cout << "Finish" << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Start
Hello
Hello 2
Hello
Hello 2
Hello
Hello 2
Hello
Hello 2
Hello
Hello 2
Finish
Bye 2
Hello
```

The problem is I could get `Bye 2` message but not `Bye` message.

I know the passed `stop_token` variable results in this problem but I do not know how to pass it to a member function inside another member function.

Comment: I believe you should've written `j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this);`. Also, destructor for `*jt` has never been triggered in the code.

Comment: @ALX23z I had tried: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues

Comment: I don't think you need to setup default values for `st` parameter, nor you need to send the token here `j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this, std::stop_token());`. `j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this);` should be fine

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] (just add the #includes) and also the output you get? If you just think about it, why would you expect `Bye` when you never stop the thread or signal the token? With `j2`, the thread is stopped when the object is destroyed.

Comment: BTW, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token: "A stop_token object is not generally constructed independently, but rather retrieved from a std::jthread or std::stop_source. This makes it share the same associated stop-state as the std::jthread or std::stop_source." In other words, when you're creating it (either by default value or explicitly), you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @NutCracker As mentioned in my previous comment, I get error by using `j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this);`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Post has been updated.

Comment: I checked c++ reference for `std::jthread`... you cannot directly invoke a member function with a stop token. You'll have to wrap the call via a lambda function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the useful comments, I have rewritten the class code as below:

```
class JT {
public:
    std::jthread j1;

    JT() {
        j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this);
    }

    void init() {
        auto st = j1.get_stop_token();
        while (!st.stop_requested()) {
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
            sleep(1);
        }
        std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You must get the stop_token on the fly through `auto st = j1.get_stop_token();`.

And the revised main function:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    JT *jt = new JT();
//    auto jt = std::make_unique<JT>();
    std::jthread j2(init_2);
    sleep(5);
    std::cout << "Finish" << std::endl;
    delete jt;
}
```

You need to `delete` the class object directly or use **RAII** (like smart pointers).

Comment: ...or just `JT jt;`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 (upvote) Yes. Including your comment.

Answer (score 11):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly (my understanding being that for `std::jthread(&JT::init, this)` jthread wants to call `JT::init(std::stop_token st, this)`, which isn't going to work), you probably want to use `std::bind_front` to give it a Callable that works.
e.g.

```
    JT() {
    j1 = std::jthread(std::bind_front(&JT::init, this));
}
```

Comment: Tnx dear. I resloved the issue and posted  just some seconds before your reply. But I will check your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The std::stop_token must be received as parameter by the JT::init function, during the thread construction. You can use either `std::bind`

```
j1 = std::jthread{ std::bind(&JT::init, this, std::placeholders::_1) };
```

or, more simpler, `std::bind_front` as in @Hasturkun answer.

**Note**
Obtaining the `std::stop_token` after the thread has been constructed as bellow, results in a race condition, because the line `j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this);` involves a constructor and a move operator, the second one concurring with the line `auto st = j1.get_stop_token();`, as demonstrated bellow:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
class JT {
public:
    std::jthread j1;

    JT() {
       j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this);
    }

    ~JT() {
        j1.request_stop();
        j1.join();
    }

    void init() {

        auto st = j1.get_stop_token();
        while (!st.stop_requested()) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }
       std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        JT jt;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms);
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
Start
Hello
Bye
Hello
Bye
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
....
```

and program never ending. I've tested on release with gcc 12.1.0 and msvc (VS 2019 16.11.5).

This can be **fixed** by using the constructor initializer list, which will not call the move operator:

```
JT() : j1(std::jthread(&JT::init, this)) {
}
```