# How do you use std::jthread::get_stop_token()?

Tags: c++, synchronization, c++20, cancellation, stdthread

I'm confused how `std::jthread::get_stop_token` is designed to work, because it seems to have an inherent race condition.

Namely, the executing thread can't simply call `std::jthread` on itself (as in [this example](/a/65701425/541686)) because it has no guarantee that the `std::jthread` object is actually constructed by the time that it begins executing. It seem to me that for a thread to use its own `get_stop_token`, it requires (at the very least) an extra event (like `std::latch`) solely to synchronize against its own construction.

However, I do not see any examples or mentions of this issue online, and so it seems to me that this may not be the intended usage. It does seem rather clunky and error-prone, as well as potentially inefficient as it requires the worker thread to block on the main thread before proceeding.

So how is `get_stop_token` supposed to be used?
Is there a simple example of the proper, intended usage of `std::jthread::get_stop_token()`?

Comment: In my opinion, it is used to know outside the thread when a stop is requested. for example in a third thread :)

Comment: The question is based on a false premise. The `jthread` object is too guaranteed to be fully constructed by the time the thread function begins executing: "**[thread.jthread.cons]/7** *Synchronization:* The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f`."

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks, that seems like a great thing to post in an answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from the example from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token) that `get_stop_token` is actually not meant to be used by the client code. It is called behind the scenes by the `std::jthread` and passed to the function called by `std::jthread`. It appears it is the way it's got to be done

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
 
void f(std::stop_token stop_token, int value)
{
    while (!stop_token.stop_requested()) {
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::jthread thread(f, 5); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that `std::jthread`s constructor detects if the function is invokable with a `std::stop_token`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/jthread

Comment: Ahh! That explains it, thanks! I guess (as someone suggested above) they probably exposed it so that outsiders can check cancellation too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700593/stdjthread-runs-a-member-function-from-another-member-function/65701425#65701425) and in the accepted answer from that question is that the line
`j1 = std::jthread(&JT::init, this, std::stop_token());` involves a constructor and move operator, the second one concurring with `auto st = j1.get_stop_token();`. This can be fixed by using the constructor initializer list, which will not call the additional move operator:

```
JT() : j1(std::jthread(&JT::init, this)) {
}
```

Thanks to [igor-tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) for clarifying that jthread object is guaranteed to be fully constructed by the time the thread function begins executing and suggesting the answer at my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75543293/race-condition-on-stdjthread-when-getting-the-stdstop-token-internally?noredirect=1#comment133295967_75543293).